# Selenium Not able to run Firefox browser from Jenkins

Tags: selenium, ubuntu, firefox, jenkins, geckodriver

I tried running Automated test using selenium on firefox through jenkins on Ubuntu Machine but not able to run it. But the same code is running without failure using Eclipse. I am running it as maven project.

Getting following error-

```
"[INFO] Running TestSuite
1524549883598   geckodriver INFO    geckodriver 0.20.0
1524549883615   geckodriver INFO    Listening on 127.0.0.1:14395
1524549883939   mozrunner::runner   INFO    Running command: "/usr/lib/firefox/firefox" "-marionette" "-profile" "/tmp/rust_mozprofile.78vmBc1aqdpF"
1524549883941   geckodriver::marionette TRACE     connection attempt 0/600
ExceptionHandler::GenerateDump cloned child 6290
ExceptionHandler::SendContinueSignalToChild sent continue signal to child
ExceptionHandler::WaitForContinueSignal waiting for continue signal...
1524549884041   geckodriver::marionette TRACE     connection attempt 1/600
1524549884141   webdriver::server   DEBUG   <- 500 Internal Server Error {"value":{"error":"unknown error","message":"Process unexpectedly closed with status signal","stacktrace":""}}
Msg Process unexpectedly closed with status signal
Build info: version: '3.11.0', revision: 'e59cfb3', time: '2018-03-11T20:26:55.152Z'
System info: host: 'Unknown', ip: 'Unknown', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '4.4.0-96-generic', java.version: '1.8.0_131'
Driver info: driver.version: FirefoxDriver
remote stacktrace:
```

Firefox version -60.0b10
Selenium -3.11.0
Using Gecko driver"

Answer (score 0):

This error message...

```
1524549884141   webdriver::server   DEBUG   <- 500 Internal Server Error {"value":{"error":"unknown error","message":"Process unexpectedly closed with status signal","stacktrace":""}}
```

...implies that the **marionette** wasn't able to initiate an active connection with the *WebClient* i.e *Firefox* browser.

Your main issue is the **version compatibility** between the binaries you are using as follows :

- Your *Selenium Client* version is **3.11.0**.
- Your *JDK version* is **1.8.0_131** which is pretty ancient.
- Your *GeckoDriver* version is **v0.20.0**.
- Your *Firefox* version is unknown to us.

So there is a clear mismatch between the *JDK v8u131* , *Selenium Client v3.11.0* and *GeckoDriver v0.20.0*.

### Solution

- Upgrade *JDK* to  recent levels [**JDK 8u162**](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/8u162-relnotes-4021436.html).
- Upgrade *GeckoDriver* to [**GeckoDriver v0.20.1**](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases) level.
- Ensure that *GeckoDriver* is present in the specified location as per your code block.
- Ensure that *GeckoDriver* is having *executable permission* for *non-root* users.
- Upgrade *Firefox* version to ***Firefox v59.0.2*** levels.
- *Clean* your *Project Workspace* through your *IDE* and *Rebuild* your project with required dependencies only.
- Use [*CCleaner*](https://www.ccleaner.com/ccleaner) tool to wipe off all the OS chores before and after the execution of your *Test Suite*.
- If your base *Web Client* version is too old, then uninstall it through [*Revo Uninstaller*](https://www.revouninstaller.com/revo_uninstaller_free_download.html) and install a recent GA and released version of *Web Client*.
- Take a *System Reboot*.
- Execute your `Test` as a non-root user.
- Always invoke `driver.quit()` within `tearDown(){}` method to close & destroy the *WebDriver* and *Web Client* instances gracefully.

Comment: Thanks , i will try this also for Ubuntu .for a while i setup my code on windows. One more question. Does Jenkins for Ubuntu does not support actual browser which a user can see.