# Lambda based on image does not work with Selenium Webdriver

Tags: docker, aws-lambda, aws-serverless, aws-lambda-containers

I would like to know the reason why my project does work locally but not as an image based lambda function in my account?

**Following commands I perform locally:**

```
 docker build -t lambda-repository .
 docker run -p 9001:8080 lambda-repository:latest
```

And in another terminal:

```
curl -XPOST "http://localhost:9001/2015-03-31/functions/function/invocations" -d '{}'
```

This results in:

```
"Google"%
```

**What happens in my AWS Account:**

- I create an ecr repository
- I push my image to it
- I use the image to create a lambda function
- invoking the lambda results in following

**ERROR:**

```
START RequestId: 2a8b9cf9-f1f0-48cb-8a5d-eb86c2dddcc0 Version: $LATEST
[ERROR] WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: crashed.
  (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
  (The process started from chrome location /usr/bin/google-chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/task/app.py", line 14, in handler
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 76, in __init__
    RemoteWebDriver.__init__(
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 157, in __init__
    self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 252, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
END RequestId: 2a8b9cf9-f1f0-48cb-8a5d-eb86c2dddcc0
REPORT RequestId: 2a8b9cf9-f1f0-48cb-8a5d-eb86c2dddcc0  Duration: 2736.59 ms    Billed Duration: 3752 ms    Memory Size: 2048 MB    Max Memory Used: 168 MB Init Duration: 1014.78 ms
```

**Dockerfile:**

```
FROM public.ecr.aws/lambda/python:3.8

RUN pwd
WORKDIR /tmp
RUN yum -y update
RUN yum -y install wget unzip
RUN yum -y install GConf2 libX11
RUN yum -y install curl

COPY download-chromedriver.sh ./
RUN /bin/bash -c "source ./download-chromedriver.sh"
RUN unzip chromedriver_linux64.zip
RUN mv chromedriver /usr/bin/chromedriver
RUN chromedriver -version

RUN curl https://intoli.com/install-google-chrome.sh | bash
RUN mv /usr/bin/google-chrome-stable /usr/bin/google-chrome
RUN google-chrome -version && which google-chrome

WORKDIR /var/task
COPY app.py ./
COPY requirements.txt ./
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt

CMD ["app.handler"]
```

**download-chromedriver.sh:**

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

CHROME_DRIVER_VERSION=`curl -sS https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/LATEST_RELEASE`
wget -N https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/$CHROME_DRIVER_VERSION/chromedriver_linux64.zip
```

**app.py:**

```
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium import webdriver


    def handler(event, context):
        options = Options()
        options.add_argument('--headless')
        options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
        options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
        options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
        options.add_argument("window-size=1280,1024")
    
        url = 'http://www.google.com'
        driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
        driver.get(url)
        text = driver.title
        return text
```

**requirements.txt:**

```
selenium==3.141.0
urllib3==1.26.2
```

Comment: I found another question with a very similar problem: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65385952/why-is-my-containerized-selenium-application-failing-only-in-aws-lambda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65385952/why-is-my-containerized-selenium-application-failing-only-in-aws-lambda)

Answer (score 0):

### This is not solution

i used this way at lambda zip. but maybe get more hint for you.

when you run `chromedriver -version` (i think it should be `chromedriver --verseion`) means running locally.

so you should type `chromedriver --version` at lambda_function.handler.
like `os.system('<chromedriver_path>/chromedriver --version')`.

and you need to set `executable_path`.
I am not sure you need `options.binary_location` as well.

```py
   def handler(event, context):
        os.system('/usr/bin/chromedriver --version')

        options = Options()
        options.add_argument('--headless')
        options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
        options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
        options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
        options.add_argument("window-size=1280,1024")
        options.binary_location = "/usr/bin/google-chrome"
    
        url = 'http://www.google.com'
        driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="/usr/bin/chromedriver", options=options)
        driver.get(url)
        text = driver.title
        return text
```

and after you succeed launch Python3.8 with chrome88 i hope share how to works.

- ref : https://github.com/adieuadieu/serverless-chrome